Favicon of website is not showing in SERP
I have a website related to fast food https://burger-king-breakfast-menu.com/ . Website is indexed in google but its favicon is not showing in SERP. Anyone here to help me. Thanks
I tried many time to change the size of favicon and again uploaded but all in vain

Updating a favicon to make it available in SERP takes time. The Google bot or any other don't scan your website every day. If your favicon is correctly displayed when you browse your website, everything should be fine.
